# The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: .net

Following is the error i am getting in the output window

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ImageEditorPlugin.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in ImageEditorPlugin.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
The program '[3884] FlirBuildIR.vshost.exe: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Please help me on this

Comment: You also need to tell us what you did to provoke this error.

Comment: i have built my application by pressing F5 and it shows the following error."---------------------------
Application failed
---------------------------
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `ImageEditorPlugin.dll` is trying to access a file that doesn't exist..

Comment: we are loading dll's during runtime from  the applicaton directory.Even though ImageEditorPlugin.dll exists in application  directory it fails to load and through's an exception

Comment: Perhaps ImageEditorPlugin is depending on additional dll's, that does not exist?

Comment: but when i open exe directly from debug/release folder it works fine.when i run it in VS2008 it through's the exception as explained above.
i have opened exe in Dependency Walker and it shows a warning for IEFRAME.DLL as "Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."

Comment: @suman Please read the error messages. They are not that scary. Clearly ImageEditorPlugin.dll is being found because the exception is raised in that DLL.

Comment: @david. Thanks for the info. i have identified the exception and able to fix that.