# Dll Import in C# metro style application

Tags: c#, windows-8, dllimport, windows-runtime

I want to use in my C# metro app function from C++ library
I'm trying to do it as usual `[DllImport("MyLibrary.dll")]` and put the dll in bin\debug folder of the application.
when it run I get an exception "Unable to load DLL `'MyLibrary.dll'`: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
What can I do please?

Answer (score 0):

> You may have a dependency on an assembly that only exists for 32-bit
>   or hasn't been properly installed in the GAC.  and follow the remarks on the [DllImportAttribute Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.dllimportattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) msdn documentation.

Ref:
 [The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430312/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-exception-from-hresult-0x8007007e)
[the specified module could not be found 0x8007007E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066180/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-0x8007007e)
[The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/netfx64bit/thread/f609f52e-00f6-4ada-9d6e-7129b85d3d4d)
[Unable to load DLL 'foo.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)](http://forums.asp.net/t/939729.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Is the DLL in your package? Add it to the project and make the type Content. If it is not deployed with your app, you can't use it.

Comment: it sounds that - that what i need but how can I do it? it C# application and c++ dll. how to add it to the project?

Comment: In solution explorer, right click project, add existing item, browse to the dll. Then in solution explorer right click the DLL and choose Properties, make sure Content is true.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with that too.
My solution has been rather simple and not given in any other place:

Copy the next two dlls in the same folder:

libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

libstdc++-6.dlll

I tried to use "mylib.dll" in a cpp coded aplication and the system asked me to include those files. And suddenly, the app I was developing didn't complain any more about not being able to find "mylib.dll". Don't asky me why.

Cheers,
Haritz Zabaleta